# identify user across ChannelHandlerContext in netty websockets

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I can not figure out how to identify the users, because the ChannelHandlerContext is not the same in the LoggingHandler and the SimpleChannelInboundHandler:

```
class WebSocketServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
@Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {                

            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

            pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
            pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
            pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler(WEBSOCKET_PATH, null, true));
            pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketIndexPageHandler(WEBSOCKET_PATH));
            pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketFrameHandler());
            pipeline.addLast(new SessionManagerAxx());   

    }
}
```

LoggingHandler :

```
class SessionManagerAxx extends LoggingHandler {

    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {

            if (evt.equals(ServerHandshakeStateEvent.HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE)) {
                   ///add the user
                    Clients.getInstance().addNewClient(ctx);
            }

            super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
    }
}
```

FrameHandler:

```
class WebSocketFrameHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<WebSocketFrame> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketFrameHandler.class);

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WebSocketFrame frame) throws Exception {
         Clients.getInstance().getClient(ctx);
        //Handle user msg
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the nodes in the pipeline do not share the ChannelHandlerContext
So I solved the problem joining the FrameHandler and the SessionManager in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

You could add something to `Channel.attr(...)` which you then use in both handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is described in "State Management" section of [ChannelHandler javadoc](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html)